# How can one get user's home directory using C++17 std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to obtain the current user's home directory and then append to it paths to other directories. Since the app is cross-platform then the approach should take this into consideration. I have been looking for a solution without success. Is there a way to get current user's home directory using C++17 std::filesystem?

Comment: @user975989 this does not work.

Comment: How many cross platforms do you need? Can you uses env{HOME} on Darwin/bsd and Linux and env{HOMEDRIVE}\env{HOMEPATH} on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The only special directories you are handed is a directory suitable for temporary files, and the current directory.

You'll have to write a OS specific wrapper for getting the home directory.  I, personally, think that is a bad idea: rather, you should have "user app settings" directory function, "user document'" directory function, etc (as determined by your application needs).  Where those directories are compared to the home directory vary on a OS by OS basis.

In my experience, also having an API for storing a "registry-like property set" is a good idea (a string-string map with serialization code on the values, for example).  It can map to plists on macOS, registry on windows, and something else on linux.

Comment: This isn't really and answer. It should be "No this is not possible"

Comment: @jennifer I covered that in sentence, paragraph and word 1.  The rest is my attempt to psychically determine what the OP is about to do wrong to solve the problem and head it off.  Appending a fixed directory to the users home directory **will** violate norms of the OS, because those norms differ significantly.

Comment: Note that on Windows the .ini format is also equally applicable. Qt's `QSettings` allows choosing between the two. A similar API to what you are discussing is Qt's [`QStandardPaths`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html). I'm not advocating throwing in a heavyweight library like Qt, but rather pointing to an existing, working solution.